# How to debug python script using CPython from C#?

Tags: c#, ironpython, cpython

I am using IronPython to execute and debug python scripts from C# project.
IronPython provides settrace() function to trace the execution of each python line.

```
IronPythonEngine.SetTrace(TracePython);

TracebackDelegate TracePython(TraceBackFrame current_frame, string current_result, object current_payload)
{
    // Code
}
```

Now, I have to use CPython instead of IronPython.
Below is the code how I run python code using CPython from C#.

```
using (Py.GIL())
            {
                dynamic sys = PythonEngine.ImportModule("sys");

                string codeToRedirectOutput =
                    "import sys\n" +
                    "from io import StringIO\n" +
                    "sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()\n" +
                    "sys.stdout.flush()\n" +
                    "sys.stderr = mystderr = StringIO()\n" +
                    "sys.stderr.flush()\n";
                PythonEngine.RunString(codeToRedirectOutput);

                string code =
                    "a = 6\n" +
                    "b = 7\n" +
                    "c = a + b\n" +
                    "print('This is a Python Example')\n" +
                    "print(c)\n";

                PythonEngine.Exec(code);
                string pyStdout = sys.stdout.getvalue();
                pyStdout = pyStdout.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
                Console.WriteLine(pyStdout);
            }
```

How to implement same settrace functionality using CPython engine in C# ?

Comment: Please clarify: how do you run CPython from C#?

Comment: I have modified my post accordingly. Please let me know in case of any concern.

Comment: All clear :) haven't used Python.Net but I assume you'd have to call sys.settrace and pass a C# function into it..